# Using selection_glyph as renderer for hovertool

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I was wondering if there is any way to use selection_glyph as the renderer of HoverTool in bokeh, i am using python and tried to add a name label to the selected glyph and then using plot.hover.names, but it does not work.

Basically i have a plot with many glyphs and i want the tooltip to appear when a glyph is selected (single click), and not when a mouse is just hovered over it? is it possible at all? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not possible with the vanilla `HoverTool` and without creating additional renderers.

The tool works with renderers, not with glyphs, and it doesn't know anything about selection. So you can either create a glyph that's rendered only when something is selected (which is finicky at best), or you can create a custom version of `HoverTool`.